# Change parameters during robot learning using simulators (Webots, Gazebo, etc)

Tags: simulation, reinforcement-learning, robotics, webots, gazebo-simu

I am searching a simulator for my robot learning research.

In the learning process, I need to change parameters of both environment (friction coefficients, terrain height in the world) and robot itself (mass, inertia).

How can simulators like Gazebo and Webots realize it?

(another problem: bisides physics engine, I also need visual reality for computer-vision-aided algorithms.
Is there any simulator that could provide both functions? )

Comment: Are you sure the robotframework tag is correct? Do you really use https://robotframework.org for testing?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. It has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Webots allows you from a [supervisor](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor) program to easily change any parameter of a simulation (including friction coefficients) while it is running. Moreover it has a [VR interface](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/computer-peripherals#virtual-reality-headset). I don't know about Gazebo.

Comment: Yes, Webots is great! I am still a beginner of Webots but my robot learning task is too complex. I would have a try and learn how to realize it. Thanks a lot!